# Retrofit and GSON - takes 10s to fetch the data

Tags: android, json, rest, gson, retrofit

I'm learning how to use Retrofit library with GSON so I can make my future apps more stable. However, I'm expecting "weird error".
I'm fetching locations from https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=san (for testing purposes)

This is my code

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SOService mService;
    private long currentTime; //start time
    private long finishedTime; //end time


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mService = ApiUtils.getClient();

        currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mService.getLocations().enqueue(new Callback<List<LocationsList>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<LocationsList>> call, Response<List<LocationsList>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.d("TAG", response.body().toString());
                    finishedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    Log.d("TAG", "It took " + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(finishedTime - currentTime) + " seconds to complete");

                }
                else{
                    Log.d("TAG","Code"+response.code());

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<LocationsList>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("TAG",t.getMessage());
            }
        });


    }
}
```

**ApiUtils**

```
public class ApiUtils {

    private static final String BASE_URL="https://www.metaweather.com/";

    public static SOService getClient(){
     return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(SOService.class);
    }
}
```

**RetrofitClient**

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit client;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl){
        if(client == null){
            client = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return client;

    }
}
```

**SOService**

```
public interface SOService {
    @GET("/api/location/search/?query=san")
    Call<List<LocationsList>> getLocations();
}
```

I've removed packages and imports for cleaner code. LocationList is POJO. When executing the code, I receive the following message:
09-25 16:23:12.913 10994-10994/pw.davor.www.retrofit D/TAG: [LocationsList{title='San Francisco'....

09-25 16:23:12.913 10994-10994/pw.davor.www.retrofit D/TAG: It took 10 seconds to complete

However, when I do the GET request in Postman, it takes about 100-300ms.

Comment: You are building a new client every invocation? Maybe create it as a singleton and reuse it. (I suppose this can be an answer, but without knowing where the code is spending its time I'm guessing. You might need to add some benchmarking code to find the hotspot. But it probably isn't the actual REST call/response.)

Comment: Also Gson is not the fastest JsonToObject conversion you can get (using Reflection heavy). Have you tried parsing the Json yourself?

Comment: (FYI, I use HUGE Gson objects with giant Retrofit responses and it never takes anywhere near 10s. I mean, how big is this list?)

Comment: @jdv Nope, it is a singleton with a slightly different approach of making it. This testing project was “built by books”, the code is from their github page. The list is fairly small, around 15 objects, each object having 4 members.

Comment: @Rafael T I didn’t.. I’m using gson for few months now and I’ve never experienced such issue

Comment: @DavorMaric ok I didn't say Gson is bad, just that it might be slow. You really should start method profiling to find where the time was spend

Comment: @DavorMaric, oh, if I actually read the code I see it's lazily instantiated. Sorry about that. Well, it's time to run some benchmarks. Re-ask: how big is the List being returned?

Comment: @jdv 11 objects.. I've tested over the emulator, the code seems to work fine now :S